# A webpage with just an audio player

Tags: human-interface-guideline, minimalist, keypad

Suppose I have a small handheld device with just a micro-controller, a keypad and a speaker. There are some pre-programmed sentences stored in the micro-controller, which can be selected by typing a number on the keypad and are played on the speaker using a built-in text-to-speech program. What would be the equivalent UI for web. I can do the technical part, but can't decide a UI that is suitable for desktop. I imagine the users would mostly use the hardware keyboard. So, what should be shown on the webpage? If I make a desktop application, I can just make a tiny window with some indicators. But how to fill a full-sized webpage? Is there any example of a standalone website with almost no visual content?

Comment: Without more context this is very hard to give an exact answer for. Have you tried anything that you can share, and have details why that isn't a suitable solution? Otherwise, the question is too broad or maybe better asked on a graphic design QA.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any example of a standalone website with almost no visual content?

Yes: The "open file in new tab" page. Here's an example: [File:Singdrossel Turdus philomelos 9919-22.mp3](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Singdrossel_Turdus_philomelos_9919-22.mp3)

The problem this has is that there only is playback for a single file. Typing on your keyboard to change file is highly unintuitive, so you probably should have some on-screen buttons which actually do trigger playback of a different file. This also would help out mobile users of your app which otherwise would have no way of doing anything.

At the end of the day, you'd probably end up with a site which behaves like one of those soundboard websites - and that's probably just about the right pattern for the job.